# How to change this jQuery code in JavaScript code briefly or also in shortly code?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".search").on("keydown",function search(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var val = $('input').val();
            if( val.length === 0 ) {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'none');
            }
            else if( val <= 3 ) {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'inline-block');
                $('#my_image').attr('src', 'images/lonely.png');
                $('h5').text('Brighten up your life with emotion packed messages!');
            }
            else if ( val >= 4 && val <= 10 ) {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'inline-block');
                $('#my_image').attr('src', 'images/positive.png');
                $('h5').text('You need to get the fastest growing language on the planet!');
            }
            else if ( val >= 11 && val <= 18 ) {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'inline-block');
                $('#my_image').attr('src', 'images/laughing_hard.png');
                $('h5').text("That's great. Ofono is perfect for you");
            }
            else if ( val >= 19 && val <= 29 ) {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'inline-block');
                $('#my_image').attr('src', 'images/cool.png');
                $('h5').text("Fantastic! You're a super user and will love Ofono");
            }
            else {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'inline-block');
                $('#my_image').attr('src', 'images/Ofonicons_v5.2-(1).png');
                $('h5').text("You're an emoji megastar. Come lead the way with Ofono");
            }    
        }
    });
})
```

I need help to change this jQuery code in JavaScript code. I don't have any idea how to do this? which explain everything shortly and understandable.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far that's not working, and we can give you some pointers?

Comment: Please attempt it yourself first and show us where you are having trouble.

Comment: Your question appears to be asking how to make the code shorter.  It's fairly succinct already - you could add an array of options to reduce the code / more maintainable, but it won't be much "better".

Comment: You might also like to take the [tour] which includes what's on topic and [ask].  Then take your question to : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple method for make that. You can create `array` for all of your data or use variable tag for each data. Below i have try with `switch` and `array`. But is it an example.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = ["images/lonely.png","images/positive.png","images/laughing_hard.png","images/cool.png","images/Ofonicons_v5.2-(1).png"];
    var txt = ["Brighten up your life with emotion packed messages!","You need to get the fastest growing language on the planet!","That's great. Ofono is perfect for you","Fantastic! You're a super user and will love Ofono","You're an emoji megastar. Come lead the way with Ofono"]
    $(".search").on("keydown",function search(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var val = $('input').val();
            if( val.length === 0 ) {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'inline-block');
                switch (val){
                    case (val <=3): $('#my_image').attr('src', img[0]); $('h5').text(txt[0]); break;
                    case (val >= 4 && val <= 10): $('#my_image').attr('src', img[1]); $('h5').text(txt[1]); break;
                    case (val >= 11 && val <= 18): $('#my_image').attr('src', img[2]); $('h5').text(txt[2]); break;
                    case (val >= 19 && val <= 29 ): $('#my_image').attr('src', img[3]); $('h5').text(txt[3]); break;
                    default: $('#my_image').attr('src', img[4]); $('h5').text(txt[4]); break;
                }
            }  
        }
    });
})
```

**UPDATE**

With a max value you can calculate the percentage of item.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = ["images/lonely.png","images/positive.png","images/laughing_hard.png","images/cool.png","images/Ofonicons_v5.2-(1).png"];
    var txt = ["Brighten up your life with emotion packed messages!","You need to get the fastest growing language on the planet!","That's great. Ofono is perfect for you","Fantastic! You're a super user and will love Ofono","You're an emoji megastar. Come lead the way with Ofono"]
    var nbMax = 50
    $(".search").on("keydown",function search(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var val = $('input').val();
            if( val.length === 0 ) {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                $('.display-emoji').css('display', 'inline-block');
                switch (val){
                    case (val <= (nbMax*10/100) ): $('#my_image').attr('src', img[0]); $('h5').text(txt[0]); break;
                    case (val >= (nbMax*11/10) && val <= (nbMax*25/100) ): $('#my_image').attr('src', img[1]); $('h5').text(txt[1]); break;
                    case (val >= (nbMax*26/100) && val <= (nbMax*40/100)): $('#my_image').attr('src', img[2]); $('h5').text(txt[2]); break;
                    case (val >= (nbMax*41/100) && val <= (nbMax*70/100) ): $('#my_image').attr('src', img[3]); $('h5').text(txt[3]); break;
                    default: $('#my_image').attr('src', img[4]); $('h5').text(txt[4]); break;
                }
            }  
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: have you an error message. because is same of your code.

Comment: i also need to set the rang in percentage in it but in jquery. how can i do that?

Comment: What is this rang ?

Comment: ranges r different means (val <= 3) for this it's in between 0 to 10 percent, (val >= 4 && val <= 10) for this it's in between 11 to 25 percent, (val >= 11 && val <= 18) for this it's 26 to 40 percent, (val >= 19 && val <= 29) for this it's 41 to 70 and (val >= 30) for this it 70+ percent

Comment: Sorry but i not understand. Percent of what? of val()? of a value defined before?

Comment: and range should be calculated automatically, if its 0 than it become 0%, if its 1 than it become 3.33%. etc

Comment: <div class="emojis">
            <ul>
                <li>
                   <p>How many emojis do you send a day?</p> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="text search" type="text" name="text" value="" />
                </li>
                <li class="display-emoji">
                    <img id="my_image" />
                    <h5></h5>  
                </li>
                <li>
                   <button class="btn btn-app">Get the app now</button> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

Comment: this is the html code and u have the jquery code. combine it and then tell me

Comment: Ok i have combined. But what you want make? because you are too obliged to separate the code for each rank.

Comment: If you want per example authorize only 50 emojis ok i understand the automated function but also i not undertand

Comment: Ok if my answer resolve your issue please valid this :)